# C++ lambda argument list

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Here is a bit of code that I'm currently using:

```
int Engine::getEntityCount(const int objectType)
{
    using namespace std;

    int total = 0;
    for_each(p_entities.begin(), p_entities.end(),
    [&objectType,&total](pair<const int, const list<Entity*>> pair)
    {   
        for_each((pair.second).begin(),(pair.second).end(),
        [&objectType,&total](Entity* &entity)
        {
            if ( entity->getAlive() == true && entity->getObjectType() == objectType )
                ++total;
        });
    });
    return total;
}
```

I'm getting the following error from intel c++:

> error : function "lambda [](Entity *&)->void::operator()"
>   cannot be called with the given argument list c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\algorithm

I'm having difficulty understanding what's wrong here. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is this really the most elegant way to code a loop over a container? If you want to be cutting-edge, why not range-based `for`?

Comment: @Potatoswatter You're right. I've just used this method because it seems the vast amount of c++ compilers at the moment support lambda, but not range based for atm. I'm also curious as to why I'm getting this error in the first place.

Comment: @dk123, If you're interested, VS2012 supports ranged-based for. GCC and Clang have since before that.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I guess I should give VS2012 a shot. Thanks for the quick replies; they've cleared everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for a non-`const` reference to a pointer to an `Entity`. The list containing that pointer is `const`. You must decide between a non-const pointer or a const list.

Comment: You're right. Which is why I originally had the code as 'const Entity*'. I get this error if I do: error : function "lambda [](const Entity *&)->void::operator()" cannot be called with the given argument list.

Comment: @dk123 You need `Entity *const &`

Comment: @dk123: That gives you a reference to a non-const pointer to a const Entity.  You want a reference to a const pointer to a non-const Entity: `Entity * const &`

Comment: @Potatoswatter Thanks for the quick replies. I should revise my const usage.

Answer (score -1):

```
....
    for_each((pair.second).begin(),(pair.second).end(),
    [&objectType,&total](const Entity* entity)
    {
        ....
    });
});
```

....